# Babel 7 - node static class method is undefined

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use babel 7 to compile a simple ES6 module (library) with a static function inside.

```
// src/index.js
class YtUrl {
    static extractIdFromUrl(url) {
        const regExp = /^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?v(?:i)?=|\&v(?:i)?=))([^#\&\?]*).*/
        const [, videoID] = url.match(regExp)
        return videoID
    }
}
```

Import the compiled module into a js node file for testing

```
const YtUrl = require('./dist/index')
console.log(YtUrl).                 // { default: [Function: YtUrl] }
console.log(YtUrl.extractIdFromUrl) // undefined
// usage: YtUrl.extractIdFromUrl('https://wwww.youtube.com/....')
```

But the `static` method is *undefined*. The following is my `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf dist && babel src --out-dir dist",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
  "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5"
}
```

And here is the `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static method exists, but you are accessing the wrong value.

`console.log(YtUrl)` shows that the value of `YtUrl` is an object with a `default` property, not a function:

```
{ default: [Function: YtUrl] }
```

That means the class is available at `YtUrl.default`:

```
console.log(YtUrl.default.extractIdFromUrl)
```

When using ES modules in a CommonJS context, default exports are usually available at the `default` property of the module object.

Comment: doesnt it look better if he wrote it like this `const YtUrl = require('./dist/index').default` so he does not need to write always `.default`?

Comment: They are free to write their code however they want. I just wanted to point out that `YtUrl` is not the class as the OP seems to assume.